# How to implement HTML5 API features in older browser

Tags: html

I'm using the features of the new browsers (HTML5 API - files prop) to get the size and the type of the uploaded files with jquery in this way.

```
$(function() {
    $('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
        //gets the size and the type of your file.
        var fsize = $('#myFile')[0].files[0].size; 
        var ftype = $('#myFile')[0].files[0].type; 
        alert("size : " + fsize + " type : " + ftype);
    });
});
```

I would like to know if I can use external libraries (Modernizr, html5shim, etc) to implement these features 
even on older browsers, such as IE8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Older Browsers doesn't support HTML5, so any of these features can't be implemented.